# gyp and node-pre-gyp fail when installing firebase with npm

Tags: firebase, npm, gyp

I'm trying to install my dependencies with npm but installation fails when firebase installation comes in. I tried to install firebase individually with `npm i firebase` but it does not work. I removed the node_modules folder, cleaned the cache and install again but it does not work either.

The first error npm shows me is a 403 error code when downloading **grpc-precompiled-binaries**. I thinks this one is the main problem and in it depends the next errors but I'm not sure. Could someone tell me how to successfully install firebase with npm?

**OUTPUT:**

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.7.2/node-v57-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.7.2 and node@8.5.0 (node-v57 ABI, musl) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.7.2/node-v57-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@8.5.0 | linux | x64
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@8.5.0 | linux | x64
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:397:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /app/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /app/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /app/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-101-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-musl/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-musl"
gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v8.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-musl/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-musl' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-101-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/app/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-musl/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-musl' (1)
npm info lifecycle grpc@1.7.2~install: Failed to exec install script
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.7.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.7.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**Last part of log file**

```
3366 info lifecycle protobufjs@5.0.2~install: protobufjs@5.0.2
3367 silly install grpc@1.7.2
3368 info lifecycle grpc@1.7.2~install: grpc@1.7.2
3369 verbose lifecycle grpc@1.7.2~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle false
3370 verbose lifecycle grpc@1.7.2~install: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/app/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin:/app/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
3371 verbose lifecycle grpc@1.7.2~install: CWD: /app/node_modules/grpc
3372 silly lifecycle grpc@1.7.2~install: Args: [ '-c',
3372 silly lifecycle   'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library' ]
3373 silly lifecycle grpc@1.7.2~install: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
3374 info lifecycle grpc@1.7.2~install: Failed to exec install script
3375 verbose unlock done using /root/.npm/_locks/staging-bd3355550c5a469e.lock for /app/node_modules/.staging
3376 warn codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
3377 warn codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
3378 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
3379 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
3380 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
3380 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
3380 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   linux
3380 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
3381 verbose stack Error: grpc@1.7.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
3381 verbose stack Exit status 1
3381 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:289:16)
3381 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
3381 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
3381 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
3381 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
3381 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
3381 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
3381 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
3382 verbose pkgid grpc@1.7.2
3383 verbose cwd /app
3384 verbose Linux 4.4.0-101-generic
3385 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "firebase"
3386 verbose node v8.5.0
3387 verbose npm  v5.3.0
3388 error code ELIFECYCLE
3389 error errno 1
3390 error grpc@1.7.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
3390 error Exit status 1
3391 error Failed at the grpc@1.7.2 install script.
3391 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
3392 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**ENV:**

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

npm: 5.3.0

node: 8.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

This answer allowed me to get my app up and running inside my alpine container. Try running this code in your development environment. Hope this helps.

> Ran into the same issue this morning. Looks like the precompiled grpc1.7.2 hasn't been uploaded for musl based distributions (alpine is musl vs glibc)
>
> For the short term, to get your build going again, and until they upload the precompiled versions, try adding this to your dockerfile
>
> ```
>  apk update && apk upgrade &&
>    apk add --no-cache python make g++
> ```
>
> python, make and g++ basically allow node-gyp to compile from source rather than >relying on the precompiled versions

---

I am running into the same problem while creating a docker image. I have noticed that when using the Linux-alpine node base image, that I get this error. However,
when using the standard node (I think Ubuntu 14.04) base image it works fine. What OS are you using? I hope you find a solution!

Comment: Thanks, now it works fine. My main OS is Ubuntu but my container has alpine.